# Apache POI docs encryption by adding a password

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I want to add a password to the docs created in Apache POI. I am unable to open the file. It said it is corrupted.

Here is the error:

[image]
[image]

Here is my encrption code:

```
static boolean encryptOne(String documentPath, String password) {
    try {
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();

        EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.standard);
        Encryptor encryptor = info.getEncryptor();
        encryptor.confirmPassword(password);

        OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new File(documentPath), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
        OutputStream os = encryptor.getDataStream(fs);
        opc.save(os);
        opc.close();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(documentPath);
        fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
        fos.close();

        System.out.println("Document successfully encrypted");

        return true;

    } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException | InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you close the `OutputStream os` after `opc.close()`? ... hint: that's where I'm finishing up the `ChunkedCipherOutputStream` and adding the padding

Comment: so I should wait until the opc.save(os) is done before closing it?

Comment: yes, just add `os.close()` after `opc.close()` and check if Word can read it. if this doesn't work, you might need to fiddle around with the encryption settings ... but first things first